# What does ::numeric and ::text mean in mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, casting, sqldatatypes

While I am practicing mysql in codewars, this query confused me because I can't find the meaning of `::numeric` and `::text` in this query.

Query: in baseball, the batting average is a simple and most common way to measure a hitter's performace. Batting average is calculated by taking all the players hits and dividing it by their number of at_bats, and it is usually displayed as a 3 digit decimal (i.e. 0.300).

Given a yankees table with the following schema,

- player_id STRING
- player_name STRING
- primary_position STRING
- games INTEGER
- at_bats INTEGER
- hits INTEGER

return a table with `player_name`, `games`, and `batting_average`.

We want `batting_average` to be rounded to the nearest thousandth, since that is how baseball fans are used to seeing it. Format it as text and make sure it has 3 digits to the right of the decimal (pad with zeroes if neccesary).

Next, order our resulting table by `batting_average`, with the highest average in the first row.

Finally, since `batting_average` is a rate statistic, a small number of `at_bats` can change the average dramatically. To correct for this, exclude any player who doesn't have at least 100 at bats.

Expected result as output:

- player_name STRING
- games INTEGER
- batting_average STRING

Solution by codewars:-

```
select player_name,
       games,
       round(hits::numeric / at_bats, 3)::text as batting_average
from yankees
where at_bats > 100
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: That's not valid MySQL syntax as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not MySQL syntax.

It's PostgreSQL syntax for typecasts, as a more concise alternative to `CAST(hits AS numeric)`.

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

> The CAST syntax conforms to SQL; the syntax with :: is historical PostgreSQL usage.

In other words, it's a non-standard syntax that only works in PostgreSQL, not in MySQL or other brands of RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
round(hits::numeric / at_bats, 3)::text
```

-->

```
RIGHT(ROUND(hits / at_bats, 3), 3)
```

Mostly, numeric values and string values are interchangeable.  So, you can *usually* get away with not casting from one to the other.

Samples:

```
mysql> SELECT RIGHT(ROUND(7 / 120, 3), 3);
+-----------------------------+
| RIGHT(ROUND(7 / 120, 3), 3) |
+-----------------------------+
| 058                         |  -- leading zero works
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT RIGHT(ROUND(120 / 120, 3), 3);
+-------------------------------+
| RIGHT(ROUND(120 / 120, 3), 3) |
+-------------------------------+
| 000                           |   -- Oops, "batting a thousande" fails
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So:

```
SELECT IF(hits = at_bats, '1000', RIGHT(ROUND(hits / at_bats, 3), 3))
```

Oops; that is not quite correct.  But who ever gets a batting average of 999.7?